Change the git timout for Jenkins multibranch pipelines
Is it possible to change the timeout for the initial git operations on a Jenkins multibranch pipeline? At the start of my job it does this, before any of my Jenkinsfile is executed:
Branch indexing
 > /tools/bin/git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /repo/details/git-2bceccf1f27ea777a6287c7beb469496/.git # timeout=10
Setting origin to /repo/details/
 > /tools/bin/git config remote.origin.url /repo/details/multibranch_test # timeout=10
Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > /tools/bin/git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.32.0'
 > /tools/bin/git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
 > /tools/bin/git fetch --tags --force --progress -- origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10

I've added both Advanced Clone and Advanced Checkout behaviors (with the timeout set to 31) and use the script console to set org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.timeOut on both the manager and agent nodes as shown below but neither seem to have an effect
println(System.getProperty("org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.timeOut"))
System.setProperty("org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.timeOut", "27")
println(System.getProperty("org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.timeOut"))

I'm aware that there are similar questions but they seem to be about how to change the timeout for git operations performed within the pipeline rather than those performed by Jenkins to actually run the job.
